# How to display data in a textarea from a file with a carriage return

Tags: html, lua, esp8266

I am trying to display input from a data stream. I am using an ESP8266-01 connected to a PIC + development board with a sensor attached (water flow). I am currently able to receive data and display it in 2 manners - constant data stream, and also a data stream with no 'zero' values (i.e., nothing prints when there is no pulse detected).

What I am having problems with is the current method of displaying/ storing data is through a text file and then printed into a `textarea` - allowing for downloading of the data. The `textarea` maxes out at 190 data points, which is not even close to the amount required.

I have 2 ideas for a solution, 1 being carriage return, so it never prints more than 1 entry at a time, or, to increase the limit of the text area. However I do not know how to do either of these things for my application.

I have a bunch of Lua scripts that I'm working on, which, unfortunately, I have been given, rather than written, so editing them is a pain as they have almost no comments. I'd rather not just hand the code out, as this is a project for a local council.

[This is the general idea of the web interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkAiT.png)

I know that this is how the reading of the sensor is handled:

```
function _M.doMeasurement()
uart.on("data", 6, function(info)
    -- Recalibration on timing error attempt
    if (#info > 3) then
        print(#info..":O\n");
    end

    local high = tonumber(string.sub(info, 1, 3));
    local low = tonumber(string.sub(info, 4, 6));

    if low or high then
        local sensorValue = 256 * high + low

        local temperature = tostring(sensorValue);
        if (_M.index < config.LOG_MAX) then
            -- calculate time value
            local time = 0
            if (_M.interval < 60) then time = _M.index*_M.interval; -- seconds
            elseif (_M.interval < 3600) then time = _M.index*_M.interval/60; -- minutes
            else time = _M.index*_M.interval/3600; -- hours
            end
            -- write log entry
                file.open(config.LOG_FILE,"a+");
                file.writeline(time..","..temperature.."&nbsp; \r");
                file.flush(); file.close()
        end
    else
    end
    _M.index = _M.index + 1;
end, 0);
uart.write(0,"WC7\n");
end
```

As you can see, I've tried putting in a `\r` at the write line, and have done this in a few other places in other files to try and get it working, but it either does nothing or crashes the server (happens a lot).